# Two types separated by a colon in Scala

Tags: scala, type-systems

I've found very interesting type variable.

```
def f[A: B, C](a: A)
class B
```

You can see it as `A: B`. This type separated by a colon. But what does it mean? Is this a some kind of synonym? And where can I use it?

Comment: Shorthand for `def f[A, C](a: A)(implicit ev: B[A])`

Answer (score 4):

That is a context bound. E.g.

```
def f[A: Ordering](a: A)
```

requires an `Ordering[A]` to be defined. To actually summon `Ordering[A]` use `implicitly[Ordering[A]]`.

Source: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html